# Understand node ordering of contraction hierarchies

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path, heuristics

Looking at wiki's description on node ordering of contraction hierarchies
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies

I can't seem to understand how they come up with this "correct" order.

I have followed some heuristics from several papers on the subject. Those most include edge difference and increasing cost of neighbors when contraction happens. (also mentioned on wiki)

Following those heuristics my algorithms looks like:

1. First run over all nodes in the graph and compute edge difference (look out/ingoing edges and subtract number of edges made through contraction).
2. Use this list for the contraction phrase. Get the node with min value. At contraction, add +1 to the cost to it's adjacency nodes.

I come up with the following contraction order which is not the same as wiki papers.

node order list after edge difference = {-1, -1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1, -1},  c = contracted.

1. Contract node 0, add +1 to node 1 as it's a neighbor.
   *node order list now = {c, 0 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1, -1}*
2. Contract node 2, add +1 to node 1 and 3.
   *node order list now = {c, 1 ,c ,0 ,-1, -1}*
3. Contract node 4, add +1 to node 3 and 5. *node order list now = {c, 1 ,c ,1 ,c, 0}*
4. Contract node 5, no neighbors.  *node order list now = {c, 1 ,c ,1 ,c, c}*
5. Contract node 1, no neighbors. *node order list now = {c, c ,c ,1 ,c, c}*
6. Contract node 3, no neighbors. *node order list now = {c, c ,c ,c ,c, c}*

[image: Contraction phase]

This only gives two shortcuts, one between 1 and 3 and the other one between 3 and 5, but missing one from 1 to 5. Wiki's example gives 3 shortcuts including the last mentioned.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you are asking what order is used in the Wikipedia example: It simply orders the node by their y-coordinate. So with your numbering, the ordering would be `2, 4,0, 3, 5, 1`. As indicated in the article, different orderings will result in a different number of edges being added during contraction, and heuristics which give orderings that result in a smaller number of edges being added during contraction are considered better. So your heuristic is better than the simple y-ordering heuristic. Which makes sense, since your heuristic selects the node with the smallest number of neighbours.